# realloc fails to reallocate a previously malloc-ed pointer

Tags: c, realloc, getchar

I'm working on a function to read a full line from `stdin` into a `char*` using `getchar()`, and it mostly works, but when I input a longer string I get

> realloc(): invalid next size: 0x00000000007ca010

Here's the function:

```
char *readCMDLine() {
    char *cmdline = malloc(sizeof(char));
    int counter = 0;
    char c;
    while (c != 10) {
        c = getchar();
        cmdline = realloc(cmdline, sizeof(cmdline) + sizeof(char));
        cmdline[counter] = c; 
        counter++;
    }
    return cmdline;
}
```

Is there a way to fix this so that I could read larger lines with it?

Comment: See what `sizeof(cmdline)` shows. It might not be what you expect. Also it's not smart to realloc after each character.

Comment: @EdHeal: The string is unterminated at that point.

Comment: @EdHeal not possible in this scenario...

Comment: Fair point above `sizeof(cmdline)` -> `counter + 1`

Comment: Other Problems: 1)`c` should be an `int` 2)Instead of using numbers like 10, use `'\n'` instead 3)`char c;
    while(c != 10)` Will the condition be true or false in the first iteration? 4)You haven't NUL-terminated the buffer.

Comment: Failing to initialise `c`. So program may randomly return nothing if `c` is randomly initialised to 10. Also not terminating the string with `'\0'` and are appending the newline to the return value. That may be as intended but very non-standard string processing.

Comment: Thanks to all the ppl who answered, it works now

Comment: suggest replacing the whole function with `getline()` with the appropriate parameters.  No need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: `sizeof(cmdline)` is the size of a pointer (typically 4 or 8 bytes)   suggest keeping a counter of the number of currently allocated memory bytes, and pass that counter as part of the second parameter to `realloc()`  always assign the returned value from `realloc()` to a temporary pointer, then check (!=NULL) that temporary pointer to assure the operation was successful, before assigning to the `cmdline` pointer.  Otherwise, when `realloc()` fails, the current pointer to allocated memory is lost, resulting in a memory leak and using that failed pointer will result in a seg fault event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code:

- You test `while (c != 10)`, but `c` is not initialized the first time and you do not allow for the file to end before the next `'\n'`.  You also assume ASCII, some systems still use EBCDIC today, where `'\n'` is not `10`.
- You realloc using `sizeof(cmdline)` instead of `counter`.  `sizeof(cmdline)` is the size of the pointer, not the currently allocated array size.
- You store `getchar()` into a `char` variable, `EOF` is not a value that can fit there, nor possibly values between `128` and `UCHAR_MAX` if `char` is signed on your platform.  Use `int` for this.
- You do not null terminate the allocated string. Neither `malloc` not `realloc` initialize the allocated memory.
- You never check for `malloc` or `realloc` failure.
- You should probably return `NULL` upon end of file, otherwise there is no way to tell end of file from sequences of empty lines.
- You reallocate the buffer for each character, this is inefficient, but can be optimized at a later stage, fix the code first.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char *readCMDLine(void) {
    char *cmdline = malloc(1);
    size_t counter = 0, size = 1;
    int c;

    if (cmdline == NULL)
        return NULL;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        char *p = realloc(cmdline, counter + 2);
        if (p == NULL) {
            free(cmdline);
            return NULL;
        }
        cmdline = p;
        cmdline[counter++] = c;
    }
    cmdline[counter] = '\0';
    if (c == EOF && counter == 0) {
        free(cmdline);
        cmdline = NULL;
    }
    return cmdline;
}
```

Here is an optimized version that calls realloc much less:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ALLOCATE_INCREMENT  100
char *readCMDLine(void) {
    char *p, *cmdline = NULL;
    size_t counter = 0, size = 0;
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        if (counter > size - 2) {
            p = realloc(cmdline, size += ALLOCATE_INCREMENT);
            if (p == NULL) {
                free(cmdline);
                return NULL;
            }
            cmdline = p;
        }
        cmdline[counter++] = c;
    }
    if (counter == 0) {
        if (c == EOF || (cmdline = malloc(1)) == NULL)
            return NULL;
    } else {
        p = realloc(cmdline, counter + 1);
        if (p != NULL)
            cmdline = p;
    }
    cmdline[counter] = '\0';
    return cmdline;
}
```

Comment: This still suffers from the undesirable 'realloc for every character' behavior.

Comment: @JohnHascall: OK, I use a similar approach as yours, but it is suboptimal: one should use a rather large automatic array and reallocate a buffer when this local array becomes too small and for the final result.  This would reduce the number of reallocations and possibly reduce fragmentation.

Answer (score 4):

Using `sizeof(cmdline)` is not doing what you expect. When used with pointers it will return the size of the pointer, not the allocated memory. This is different for arrays defined at compile time.

You can use the `counter` variable to keep track how many bytes are already allocated.

Also one style thing: `sizeof(char)` is always 1 so it is unnecessary.

It is not performant to realloc after each character. It would be better to allocate a buffer of decent size and when it's full allocate a bigger one.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is,

```
 sizeof(cmdline)
```

does not work the way you think it is. You cannot get the size of the allocated memory using `sizeof` on a pointer. You have to keep track of the size yourself.

Now, to add a bit on the error,

> realloc(): invalid next size: 0x00000000007ca010

basically what happens is,

```
cmdline = realloc(cmdline, sizeof(cmdline) + sizeof(char));
```

does not actually *resize* the allocated memory as you would have thought. So, when the `counter` value is large enough to point to an out-of-bound memory in case of `cmdline[counter]`, you essentially invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). So, due to the UB (and subsequent memory corruption), `realloc()` emits the error and throws a segmentation fault as a side effect.

Also, to add

- Point 1:

  ```
   pointer = realloc(pointer....)
  ```

  is a very bad syntax to use. In case `realloc()` fails, you'll end up losing the actual memory, too, as it will get replaced by NULL.
- Point 2:

  [`getchar()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) returns an `int` and all the return values may not fit into a `char` (ex. `EOF`). Change the type of `c` to `int`.
- Point 3:

  You may want to null terminate your *string* before returning it to make it usable with string manipulation functions and a perfect suit for `%s` in `printf()`.
- Point 4:

  You should be checking for the success of `malloc()` and `realloc()` before using the returned pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Combining all the suggestions:

```
#define BYTES_TO_ADD 80     /* a rather arbitrary number */

char * readCMDLine ( void ) {
    char * cmdline = NULL;
    size_t cmdSize = 0;
    size_t cmdLen = 0;
    int    c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (cmdLen == cmdSize) {
            char * tmp = realloc(cmdline, (cmdSize += BYTES_TO_ADD));  
            if (tmp == NULL) { free(cmdline); return NULL; } 
            cmdline = tmp;
        }
        cmdline[cmdLen++] = (c == '\n') ? '\0' : c;
        if (c == '\n') return cmdline;
    }
    return NULL;   /* no newline */
}
```

Comment: Obviously what to do with an incomplete line is up to the implementer.  I choose to consider it an invalid input.  Others might choose to return the partial result.

Comment: So does the infamous `gets()` and the non standard but useful `getline()` functions.  To make a different choice is of course a design decision, but a surprising one.